# How to create a system image of windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-7

I want to create a system image which does not contains any of my user programs(SQL Server, Visual Studio, etc...), I need to just the operating system files only.

Is it possible with windows 7 operating system? if so please guide me.

Comment: I don't think this belongs in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Click on Start --> Accesories --> Getting Started --> Back up your files.

Click on the Create a system image hyperlink (top left).

Save this image to your hard disc, external drive etc. (On this screen you need to decide). Click next.

That is all.